# What is the difference between solve(a) and ginv(a) in R?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am working on matrix operations in R. I came across 2 different methods to find inverse of a matrix namely:

- `MASS::ginv(a)`
- `solve(a)`

They returns the same result or so it seems but when I try to equate them using `ginv(a) == solve(a)` only elements of leading diagonal seem to be equal. It returns True for those elements otherwise it returns zero.

I am perplexed with this behavior. This is happening even though I can see that they have exactly same numerical values.

I am working on R Studio and Windows.

```
 library(MASS)
 a1 <- rbind(c(1,-0.25),c(-0.25,1))
 solve(a1)
 ginv(a1)
 solve(a1) == ginv(a1)
```

Please somebody explain to me what is happening. Is it because of pseudo inverse?

Comment: These solutions are identical to machine tolerance.  You should use `all.equal` to test for equality.

Comment: @Andrie, I see you fixed your hammer ;)